# Get hit or get a hit

Tags: grammar

1. Did you get hit on your leg?
2. Did you get a hit on your leg?

Is #2 correct as well? How do they different and when do you use hit with no article and with an article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit can be used as a verb (your example 1) or a noun (your example2).

By using the verb we focus on the action of hitting, something hitting something, the process that occurred.

By using the noun we focus more on the event, the instant of the collision.

The noun usage is less common. The noun usage has other meanings: in baseball there is the concept of **a hit** and in gangster movies an assassination is referred to as **a hit**.

Answer (score 0):

Neither use of *hit* seems idiomatic to me (American English). We might say *bumped* and *a bump* instead.

For hit we might say *Did you get hit in the leg?*